# How to calculate running total + total remaining in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have this set of data in Excel:

```
Date  | Year | Spend | Budget | Product 
Jan   | 2017 | 300   | 350    | Pencils
Feb   | 2017 | 450   | 450    | Pencils
March | 2017 | 510   | 520    | Pencils
...   | ...  | ...   |
Dec   | 2017 | 234   | 240    | Pencils
Jan   | 2018 | 222   | 222    | Pencils
Feb   | 2018 | 458   | 500    | Pencils
March | 2018 | 345   | 400    | Pencils
...   | ...  | ...   | 
Dec   | 2018 | 600   | 600    | Pencils
```

I'm trying to build a pivot table that shows:

RT stands for "running total"

Av stands for "available"

```
Year   | 2017 
       | Jan  | RT | Av  | Feb | RT | Av | March | RT | Av
Pencils| 300  | 300| 50  | 450 | 750|  50|  510  |1260| 60
```

In brief, "available" = running total + budget for remaining months. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will be able to accomplish this with a pivot table.  Best would be vba.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid that would be the solution, but I have no expertise on vba.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

available = sum(budget) - sum(spent)

running total = sum(spent)

You should add a column for running total, that will sum the spent column from the beginning up to current row.

And add a column for available, that will sum the budget column from the beginning up to current row, and will reduce the value of the "running total" column (of the same row) from it.